# Why does my file copy not rename but duplicate?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm copying the newest backup file from a network share and then stripping out the date/time from the file name.  Problem is I end up with 2 copies instead of a single renamed file:

`$input` is the path to copy from

`$output` is the destination path

```
    "...copying latest backup from $input..."
    Get-ChildItem $input | sort LastWriteTime -desc | select -first 1 | cpi -dest $output
    "...renaming to standard convention..."
    # clean up numbers out of the file names
    dir $output | rename-item -NewName { $_.name -replace "_?[0-9]","" }
```

After the copy operation finishes, I have 2 files:

```
PS>dir
databasename_backup.bak
databasename_backup_2013_11_11_212322_1217596.bak
```

The file with the date/time shows up in the destination folder first, then I see "...renaming to standard convention..." and then the clean file name shows up.  It appears to be copying and not renaming. I'm missing something obvious but I need someone to point it out to me...

Comment: Hmm, I can't repro what you're seeing.  The original file doesn't have any special attributes like Hidden does it?

Comment: You have to narrow the problem. First check that $output contains the files you are expecting. Second try renaming a single item. If you narrow it down, you will probably find the answer, or at least you will have a better question.

Answer (score 0):

I was stupid - there was a duplicate line further in the script that copied the source file again. I must have pasted it there without knowing...thanks for taking the time.